# Why do I get "uninitialized constant" when creating custom hash class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails, I'm trying to create a custom hash class,  So I created a file in lib/core_ext/hash_with_variants.rb with this content

```
class VariantsHash < Hash
  def []=(string, value)
    all_variants(string).each do |variant|
      super(variant, value)
    end
  end

  def [](string)
    all_variants(string).detect do |variant|
      super(variant)
    end
  end

  private

  def all_variants(string)
    downcase_string = string.downcase
    string_length = string.length

    variants = [downcase_string]

    string_length.times do |i|
      variants << downcase_string[0, i] + downcase_string[i + 1 , string_length]
    end

    variants
  end
end
```

but when I try and initialize a new object using

```
VariantsHash.new
```

I get the error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant VariantsHash
```

What else do I need to be doing to get this right?

Comment: In your initializers are you loading your lib file(s)? (Or config, I forget where that line lives.)

Comment: as @DaveNewton suggests, it looks like you need to add this file to your loaders or otherwise `require` this file in the code where you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require the file in your `/config/application.rb`.

Comment: This doesn't open the built-in class, it subclasses it.

Comment: oh indeed. my bad.